# html5 dragand drop persistent

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, persistent

How would i go about making a drag and drop stay where i put it?
Im tryin to use drag and drop to setup a formation on a footbal/soccer pitch (before a match)

Im able to drag and drop the players on the pitch, however this is not persistent ofcourse, a reload will reset it ofcourse.

How would i go about making it persistent?

```
<style type="text/css">
#maindiv {width:566px; height:800px;background-image: url('http://www.tabor-    sezana.com/football%20pitch.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;position:relative;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
background-size:80%;background-position:right top;}
#div1 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa; position:relative;  left:170px; top:120px;}
#div2 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; top:120px; left:305px; }
#div3 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; left:440px; top:-20px;}
#div4 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; left:305px; top:140px; }
#div5 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; left:160px; top:160px;}
#div6 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; left:450px; top:100px;}
#div7 {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;position:relative; left:305px; top:110px;}
</style>
<?php if ($_SESSION[rechten] >= 3 ){
?>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
 }
</script>
<?php
}
?>

<br />
<div style="width:680px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
<?php

            $data212 = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users where    speler='1'");
      foreach($data212 as $row) { 
     ?>
 <img id="drag<?php print_r($row[id]); ?>" src="<?php print_r($row[avatar]); ?>"     draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
<?php
}
?>
</div>
<div id="maindiv">





<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div7" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i could make a db table with the positions etc, and then fill the image on the right spot, however i want to be able to do this with drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

You could HTML5 localstorage to store the position values but HTML5 doesn't have built in persistence for drag and drop elements.